# Combining two datasets - appending and merging rows according to dummy variable

Tags: r, merge, dummy-variable

I am compiling two files on excel (file_a and file_b) to help me develop a plan to merge several surveys covering various countries. I would like to **use R to check whether the variables I am interested at have good coverage across countries**, but I am having a hard time combining the two files I compiled. Ideally, **I want to combine my files to get a dataset in the following way:**

| Countries | variable1 | variable2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| country1 | 0 | 1 |
| country2 | 1 | 1 |
| country3 | 0 | 0 |

File_a shows whether countries are included in given survey waves:

| Countries | survey_wave1 | survey_wave2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| country1 | 0 | 1 |
| country2 | 1 | 1 |
| country3 | 0 | 0 |

File_b shows which variables are included in each survey waves:

| Survey_wave | variable1 | variable2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| survey_wave1 | 0 | 1 |
| survey_wave2 | 0 | 0 |
| survey_wave3 | 1 | 0 |

**The names of the waves are unique, but the countries repeat across waves, and my guess is that this complicates things..**
I am thinking that maybe this is one of those situations where the solution is quite simple, but at this point I really cannot wrap my head around it. So whoever can help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You could reshape file_a to a long format—columns would be country & survey wave—and join that with file_b, using survey wave as the joining column

Comment: Thanks Camille!